# Ansible bigip_command module

Tags: ansible, f5

Is there a way you can ignore an error "wait_for" throws when a conditional statement hasn't been satisfied?

In my play, I have a task to see which LTM in the pair is active, and it fails when it hits the standby (which makes sense).

But it would be nice if you could ignore this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_yIW5Ex/ansible_module_bigip_command.py", line 691, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ansible_yIW5Ex/ansible_module_bigip_command.py", line 680, in main
    results = mm.exec_module()
  File "/tmp/ansible_yIW5Ex/ansible_module_bigip_command.py", line 617, in exec_module
    result = manager.exec_module()
  File "/tmp/ansible_yIW5Ex/ansible_module_bigip_command.py", line 409, in exec_module
    changed = self.execute()
  File "/tmp/ansible_yIW5Ex/ansible_module_bigip_command.py", line 498, in execute
    raise FailedConditionsError(errmsg, failed_conditions)
ansible.module_utils.network.common.parsing.FailedConditionsError: One or more conditional statements have not been satisfied.

fatal: [x.x.x.x -> localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_yIW5Ex/ansible_module_bigip_command.py\", line 691, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_yIW5Ex/ansible_module_bigip_command.py\", line 680, in main\n    results = mm.exec_module()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_yIW5Ex/ansible_module_bigip_command.py\", line 617, in exec_module\n    result = manager.exec_module()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_yIW5Ex/ansible_module_bigip_command.py\", line 409, in exec_module\n    changed = self.execute()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_yIW5Ex/ansible_module_bigip_command.py\", line 498, in execute\n    raise FailedConditionsError(errmsg, failed_conditions)\nansible.module_utils.network.common.parsing.FailedConditionsError: One or more conditional statements have not been satisfied.\n", 
    "module_stdout": "", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 1
```

And here is the task I'm working with: (Note: the host inventory file contains 2 IPs only)

```
  - name : Checking which LTM is active....
    bigip_command:
      server: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      user: "{{ remote_username }}"
      password: "{{ remote_passwd }}"
      commands:
        - "tmsh show sys failover"
        - "tmsh list /sys management-ip  | grep -o x.x.x.x"
      wait_for:
        - result[0] contains active
      validate_certs: no
    delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the module documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/bigip_command_module.html) -- There is a "match" directive that defaults to "all" which implies that in the "wait_for" section all checks should pan out as true. You can explicitly set this to "any" which would make your run pass if at least 1 condition in "wait_for" is met.

You also have a "retries" and "interval" flag which will tell the module how many retries to make and how far apart they should be, respectively.

I hope this helps.

Cheers!